# Why I'm not getting full width in vertical mobile?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to design a web with Bootstrap and Adobe dreamweaver and it works fine in desktop, horizontal view in mobiles and other views but whenever I choose to display it on vertical smartphones, the containers don't use the full width. Some code:

HTML

```
         <div class="container-fluid">
            <h1>¿Qué servicios ofrecemos?</h1>
            <br>
            <div class="row">
               <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-4">
                  <div class="card-header" style="width: 100%"></div>
                  <div class="card-body" style="width: 100%">
                     <h5 class="card-title">Diseños web responsive</h5>
                     <br>
                     <img style="width: 80%; margin-left: 10%" src=".\images\responsive.png">
                  </div>
                  <div class="card-footer text-muted" style="width: 100%">Nos encargamos de que tu sitio web luzca profesional y se adapte por igual a todos los dispositivos en los que se visualice.</div>
               </div>
               <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-4">
                  <div class="card-header"></div>
                  <div class="card-body">
                     <h5 class="card-title">Traducción de tu sitio web</h5>
                     <br>
                     <img style="width: 100%" src=".\images\traduccion.png">
                  </div>
                  <div class="card-footer text-muted">Traducimos tu sitio web a Español, Inglés y Polaco. Consulta nuestras tarifas de traducción.</div>
               </div>
               <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-4">
                  <div class="card-header"></div>
                  <div class="card-body">
                     <h5 class="card-title">Personalización</h5>
                     <br>
                     <img style="width: 100%" src=".\images\personalizacion.png">
                  </div>
                  <div class="card-footer text-muted">Diseñamos los elementos gráficos de tu web para que tenga su propia personalidad.</div>
               </div>
            </div>
      </section>
```

I expect this to show as:

Column 1 | Column 2 | Column 3 in desktop

and one above another in mobile. I would like to keep the original 1|2|3 format but I don't know who. Thing is it works as expected but doesn't get the full width. This is only an example, the problem occurs in the whole site.

CSS

```
html{
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

body {
  padding-top: 56px;
}

.bg-image-full {
  background: no-repeat center center scroll;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
}

.custom-control-input:checked~.custom-control-label::before {
    color: white !important;
    background-color: green !important;
}
```

Some images of the problem

[Desktop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BGv2L.jpg)

[Mobile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PuRqz.jpg)

It's truly weird since I respected the grid documentation, is the only thing I suspected to be causing this and it's not the case. I'm just trying to learn, don't be too harsh if I missed something.

Edit: I know I'm using 'br' and independent style tags, I use them at first and then use CSS, is just for the beginning, because I sometimes I don't want to be switching tabs lol.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi , please add jsfiddle or plunker like this scenario to get instant reply , this will be difficult for others to answer

Comment: show up the whole of html code your navbar is missing

Comment: https://codepen.io/pp-paul/pen/JjodWPM - without your <section tag is working ok. So you must be missing code that is causing it.

Comment: You do have a <meta name="viewport">, right?

Comment: What should I do then? I post the whole code with a comment or in JsFiddle? What do you prefer?

Comment: Deleting section works like a charm. Now I'm facing the problema that when you choose computer view on mobile the mail header image disappears